# WordPress excerpt adding social share button text

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added a share button on my WordPress theme and then appended it to the top of the page with `the_content` and it worked well just that when I checked my home page I saw that the text on the social button e.g. Facebook, Google Plus, Twitter and the rest are showing up (in plain text though).

However, I made another piece of code that appends it immediately after the content which works perfectly. I mean the excerpt didn't add the social icon text, after all the limit is 30 word character.

I want to remove these buttons showing up in the excerpt when it's been appened to the top. I mean before the content.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: screenshot of my question]

Here is my code, if required modification.

```
/* social share icons */

function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
global $post;
if(is_singular() || is_home()){

    // Get current page URL 
    $crunchifyURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

    // Get current page title
    $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

    // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
    $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

    // Construct sharing URL without using any script
    $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
    $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
    $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
    $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;
    $linkedInURL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;title='.$crunchifyTitle;
    $whatsappURL = 'whatsapp://send?text='.$crunchifyTitle . ' ' . $crunchifyURL;

    // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
    $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

    // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
    $variable .= '<!-- Crunchify.com social sharing. Get your copy here: http://crunchify.me/1VIxAsz -->';
    $variable .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-whatsapp" href="'.$whatsappURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>WhatsApp</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Google+</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>Buffer</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-linkedin" href="'.$linkedInURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>LinkedIn</a>';
    $variable .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i>Pin It</a>';
    $variable .= '</div>';

    return $variable.$content;
}else{
    // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
    return $variable.$content;
}
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin or a function within your theme to create your excerpt? The auto-created excerpt using the WP Core function takes from `the_content`, strips all HTML tags and shortcodes and has a default length of 55 words.

If you want to specifically exclude this block, you can add a small function to your theme's functions.php or a site-specific plugin, which (as long as it's not named the same as other functions) can go along with other filters for `the_excerpt`:

```
function excerpt_strip_content_share_buttons( $excerpt ) {
    $regex = '(<div class="crunchify-social">)((\s)*(<a\s.*a>))+(\s*<\/div>){1}'; \\ specifically for that block of your 'a' tags, does not affect other divs
    $excerpt = preg_replace($regex,'', $excerpt);
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'excerpt_strip_content_share_buttons', 0);
```

Comment: hello , thansk for your response i really appreciate it, i placed the above code you mentioned , it surely did remove the <div class="crunchify-social"> but it also generated an error `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier`

Answer (score 0):

i figured this out a different way thou, wish there is a mark as answered button right now i would have clicked on it, i discovered why its showing was because it was in `the-content` and the excerpt tries to strip off images, div classes, shortcodes, html tags and many more leaving only pure text.

so what i did was

1. i created a new code added a short code to it and called it with `acardio-social` then called it after the header, this time not within `<?php the-content(); ?>` and to make it more better its a mere shortcode not even a div class thus as long as it is carrying a function it is excluded completely from the `<?php the-excerpt()?>` i think this method is the best i can do .
2. i added a function to get title i also tried the thus making it able to run on the `while ('have_posts()')` condition, thus it generates different share url on a list of 5 post.

here is the code, if it would help any body.

```
/* social share icons */

/**
* Shortcode function ish
*/
add_shortcode( 'acardio-social', 'nerd_social_share_plugin_shortcode' );
function nerd_social_share_plugin_shortcode( $attr ) {
global $plugin_code;
   // Get current page URL 
$crunchifyURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

// Get current page title
$crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

// Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
$crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

// Construct sharing URL without using any script
$twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
$facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
$googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
$bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;
$linkedInURL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;title='.$crunchifyTitle;
$whatsappURL = 'whatsapp://send?text='.$crunchifyTitle . ' ' . $crunchifyURL;

// Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
$pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

echo '<div class="crunchify-social">';

echo '<div class="acardio-post-social-icons">';

echo '
    <!--Facebook-->
    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>

    <!-- twiiter -->

    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>



    <!--Google Plus-->
   <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Google+</a>

    <!-- whatsapp -->
    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-whatsapp" href="'.$whatsappURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>WhatsApp</a>


    <!--Reddit-->
    <a  class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" target="_blank" href="http://reddit.com/submit?url='. get_permalink() .'&amp;title='. the_title('', '', FALSE) .'" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>Reddit</a>

    <!--buffer-->
    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>Buffer</a>

    <!--LinkedIn-->
    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-linkedin" href="'.$linkedInURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>LinkedIn</a>

    <!--Pinterst-->
    <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i>Pin It</a>

    ' .
    "
</div>
</div>";
}
```

Mind you its open to modification.